# How to set host IP in zabbix LLD host discovery

Tags: zabbix

I am using zabbix 2.4 LLD( low level discovery) to discover hosts in my system.
I have a script which returns Host names in JSON format as described  in https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery.
All works fine and new host are created, but their IP address is set to an IP adress of a host their i am running discovery script.
How can I set discovered host IP?

Host Discovery screenshot
[image: Host Discovery screenshot]
Discovered host
[image: Discovered host]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low-level discovery for hosts was originally implemented for VMware in [ZBXNEXT-1633](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1633), where discovered hosts should apparently use the same address as vCenter or vSphere.

Unfortunately, what you want is currently not possible, but you can follow [ZBXNEXT-2717](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-2717) to be notified when it is implemented.